# Sub-class of String, when called, binds argument to both parameters of __init__?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, oop

In Python 2.7, the following class statement, when run with
a string as its argument, appears to bind that string to both
of the arguments of **init** ('self' and 'grasshopper').

Methods can be defined that operate with seemingly identical
results on self and self.grasshopper.

I note that if **init** is defined to take three arguments -- e.g.,
'self', 'grasshopper', and 'beetle' -- the class, when
run with two string arguments (e.g., CrazyString('spam', 'eggs')), raises the error:

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

This suggests to me that 'str' is not just being inherited
by the class CrazyString, but executed as a function.

I do not understand what is happening, and I therefore feel
unsure whether I should be writing methods to operate on self
or on self.grasshopper.  Or are self and self.grasshopper actually
the same?

```
class CrazyString(str):

    def __init__(self, grasshopper):
        self.grasshopper = grasshopper

    def backwards1(self):
        return self.grasshopper[::-1]

    def backwards2(self):
        return self[::-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cs = CrazyString('spam')
    print cs
    print cs.grasshopper
    print cs.backwards1()
    print cs.backwards2()
```

When run ('python crazy.py'), I get the following output:

```
spam
spam
maps
maps
```

Comment: hmm... since no-one bothers to ask, why do you subclass str in the first place?

Comment: @user689003, I want to illustrate the main ideas of Python OOP -- self and inheritance -- to undergraduates that already know strings, lists, and dictionaries. Subclassing things like string lets us focus on self and inheritance in a manner simple enough for them to write some rudimentary methods, then learn to write unit tests for adding one or two more methods, before the semester ends in June.

Comment: would advice you to just use arbitrary classes, not strings. As you can see inheriting from `str` is not as trivial one would hope and the `__new__` concept is very python specific and not necessarily OOP related + can be confusing to boot! then you have the deal about `str` being immutable as well which I'm sure would cause some hair pulling

Comment: @user3012759 thank you - I followed your advice and dropped the idea of using a sub-class of `str` when introducing OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer: explaining where the `str` initialization takes place (since you don't call `str.__init__`), and explaining "where `str` stores the string".

First, since `str` is an immutable type implemented in C, `str.__init__` isn't actually involved in initializing the string. There's another method, `__new__`, that Python calls to create instances of a type before `__init__` initializes them, and for immutable types like `str`, `__new__` creates the object pre-initialized. (After all, if `__init__` initialized the string, that would be a mutation.)

Second, `self` appears to be a string because it's *supposed* to be a string. You're inheriting from `str`, so instances of your class are instances of `str`; they're strings! You can `print` them like strings and slice-reverse them like strings and everything, because they inherit all that from `str`. You don't need to "get at the underlying string" with something like `self.str`, like people sometimes expect.

Comment: This explanation is enormously helpful.  I tried to respond here with code based on your explanation but see that code examples do not fit here -- see above.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you stumble over the `__new__` function which makes you trouble.

You should do something like (untested!)

```
class CrazyString(str):

    def __new__(cls, grasshopper, beetle):
        return cls(grasshopper) # not sure if that works, maybe we have to use super() in any way...

    def __init__(self, grasshopper, beetle):
        self.grasshopper = grasshopper
        self.beetle = grasshopper

    def backwards1(self):
        return self.grasshopper[::-1]

    def backwards2(self):
        return self[::-1]

    def backwards3(self):
        return self.beetle[::-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cs = CrazyString('spam')
    print cs
    print cs.grasshopper
    print cs.backwards1()
    print cs.backwards2()
    print cs.backwards3()
```

Comment: In my case, I do not actually need to pass more than one string as an argument and really tried that only to see if the attempt would provide any useful clues.  But this is very interesting - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the string 'spam' is turned into an object of type 'str' by the `__new__` method before it is even passed to `__init__` as the second parameter.

If there is an `__init__` with any number of parameters but two, then the call `CrazyString('spam')` will fail and exit with a TypeError. This works:

```
class CrazyString(str):
    def backwards(self):
        return self[::-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cs = CrazyString('spam')
    print cs
    print cs.backwards()
```

Comment: Just remove that useless `__init__()` method here.

Comment: thank you @BlackJack - removing `__init__()` works.  So it works without `__init__()` or with `__init__()` and the propert number of parameters, but if the number of parameters is wrong, the class cannot be called (raises an exception).